# Is the rhyme scheme about the ending sound or two sounds?

Tags: poetry, rhymes

I'm an English language arts teacher, and I teach poetry. Used to tell my students that the rhyme scheme is about the ending sound of each line; like AABB, ABAB, etc. And when you find multiple lines end in the same sound, you should assign the same letter for them when writing the scheme.

What I noticed (in poems I'm familiar with) is that lines with the same rhyme letter would usually have the same last two sounds, NOT ONE sound!

Examples to make my point clear:
A dog is crying
Oh it's dying

You see here the ending two sounds are the same (the sound of y /aɪ/and the sound of ing /ŋ/).

Then I got confused when I read a poem that have similar endings of one sound only.

Example 1:
A free bird leaps
A caged one stacks

See here only the s sound is repeated. When writing the rhyme scheme, should I assign the same letter for both line, or aren't they rhyming?

Is the rhyme scheme here AA or AB?

Example 2:
Open the door
Take the flower
Look at the star

See here only the r sound is repeated. Are they rhyming?

Is my rhyme scheme AAA or ABC?

My basic question is: is the rhyme scheme about the ending sound or the ending two sounds?

Comment: Doesn't always need two sounds. Dying and crying rhyme their stressed syllables. A last letter does not make a rhyme, only a last syllable. "Door, flower, star" do not rhyme, but door and drawer are okay, and door and dare are *near rhymes*.

Comment: Example 1 does not rhyme. The last letter matching does not make a rhyme. Sometimes there is a close ryhme where the last letters differ: *he paid his pence, now he repents*.

Comment: Not all that is classed as poetry even rhymes at all. See 'free verse'.

Comment: There are actually **many different kinds of rhyming (or *almost*-rhyming) pairs**. Here is a nice overview: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyme. Note that the dictionary definition for "rhyme" is fairly imprecise and seems to refer to **any/all** of these: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rhyme

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not inherently about the English language (I don't believe 'rhyming' in English—including the disagreements surrounding it—differs (substantially) from 'rhyming' in German or Dutch, for example).